# About the smallest value of B

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, solution-verification, maxima-minima

I am trying to solve this problem:
We know that there's a inequality: $$(3n-1)(n+B)\geq A(4n-1)n$$
When $A=\frac{3}{4}$, what is the smallest possible value of B.
So, what I did is that:
$$B\geq \frac{\frac{3}{4}n(4n-1)-n(3n-1)}{3n-1}$$
We can deduce that:
$$B\geq \frac{3n(4n-1)-4n(3n-1)}{4(3n-1)}$$
Expand and simplifies:
$$B\geq \frac{1}{12-\frac{1}{n}}$$
We know that when n is greater, the denominator of the RHS would be greater, meaning that RHS would be smaller. So, the smallest value of RHS would result in the smallest value of LHS.
When $n \to \infty$: The RHS $\to$ $\frac{1}{12}$.
I thought that the smallest value of B should be $\frac{1}{12}$. But, it turns out to be $\frac{1}{8}$.
Note: $n\geq 1$, and n is integers.
May I know why my method doesn't work? thank you so much.

Comment: The question is what the question actually means. Are they asking for the smallest value of $B$ that works for *some* $n$ or are they asking for the smallest value of $B$ that works for *all* $n$? If the former, the answer is $B=1/8$ with $n=1$; if the latter, the answer is $B=1/12$, as you said.

Comment: I think is just the positive integers of n, I believe why my method wrong is because the infinite does not exist, and I didn’t understand the question.

Comment: The question, as I said, is very vaguely stated. I would have solved it the same way you did.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I agree with you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it should be $$B\geq\frac{1}{12-\frac{4}{n}}.$$

The minimal value of $\frac{1}{12-\frac{4}{n}}$ does not exist bu the infimum is equal to $\frac{1}{12}.$

Also, fo $n\geq1$ we obtain: $$\frac{1}{12-\frac{4}{n}}\leq\frac{1}{8}.$$

Thus, the minimal value of $B$ for which the inequality $$B\geq\frac{1}{12-\frac{4}{n}}$$ is true for any natural $n$ it's $$B=\frac{1}{8}.$$

Comment: Right, so as I just commented, the issue is what the question actually is asking ...

Comment: thank you, I finally got why my method is wrong, since the infinity does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Find the smallest and greatest value of $B\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb N$ such that $$(3n-1)(n+B)\geq \frac34(4n-1)n$$

$$B\geq\frac{1}{12-\frac{4}{n}}$$
Draw the graph $y$ vs $n$.

- $y=0$ for $n=0$.
- Asymptote $\Rightarrow\text{ greatest }y=\frac1{12}$ as $n\to +\infty$.
- Asymptote $y\to-\infty$ as $n\to \frac13$.
- Smallest $y=\frac1{8}$ for $n=1$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ Henry Cai Your method is correct! Maybe you have a typo in your answer key. The smallest value is $1/12$ and the highest $1/8$. Consider the part of the graph from $n=1$ onwards only.